# Quadratic in Java

Tags: java

Could any help me start?

Using a class that I created before, I need to make a new class that specifically deals with QuadPoly. I think I have the constructors made correctly but i'm not a hundred percent sure.

```
public class Poly {

private float[] coefficients;
public static void main (String[] args){
    float[] fa = {3, 2, 4};
    Poly test = new Poly(fa);

}

public Poly() {
    coefficients = new float[1];
    coefficients[0] = 0;
}

public Poly(int degree) {
    coefficients = new float[degree+1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= degree; i++)
        coefficients[i] = 0;
}


public Poly(float[] a) {
    coefficients = new float[a.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        coefficients[i] = a[i];
}

public int getDegree() {
    return coefficients.length-1;
}

public float getCoefficient(int i) {
    return coefficients[i];
}

public void setCoefficient(int i, float value) {
    coefficients[i] = value;
}

public Poly add(Poly p) {
    int n = getDegree();
    int m = p.getDegree();
    Poly result = new Poly(Poly.max(n, m));
    int i;

        for (i = 0; i <= Poly.min(n, m); i++) 
            result.setCoefficient(i, coefficients[i] + p.getCoefficient(i));
        if (i <= n) {
            //we have to copy the remaining coefficients from this object
            for ( ; i <= n; i++) 
                result.setCoefficient(i, coefficients[i]);
        } else {
            // we have to copy the remaining coefficients from p
            for ( ; i <= m; i++) 
                result.setCoefficient(i, p.getCoefficient(i));
        }
    return result;
}

public void displayPoly () {
    for (int i=0; i < coefficients.length; i++)
        System.out.print(" "+coefficients[i]);
    System.out.println();
}

private static int max (int n, int m) {
    if (n > m)
        return n;
    return m;
}

private static int min (int n, int m) {
    if (n > m)
        return m;
    return n;
}

public Poly multiplyCon (double c){
    int n = getDegree();
    Poly results = new Poly(n);
    for (int i =0; i <= n; i++){ // can work when multiplying only 1 coefficient
        results.setCoefficient(i, (float)(coefficients[i] * c)); // errors ArrayIndexOutOfBounds for setCoefficient
       }

    return results;
   }

public Poly multiplyPoly (Poly p){
    int n = getDegree();
    int m = p.getDegree();
    Poly result = null;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++){
        Poly tmpResult = p.multiByConstantWithDegree(coefficients[i], i); //Calls new method
        if (result == null){
            result = tmpResult;
        } else {
            result = result.add(tmpResult);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
  public void leadingZero() {
    int degree = getDegree();
    if ( degree == 0 ) return;
    if ( coefficients[degree] != 0 ) return;
    // find the last highest degree with non-zero cofficient 
    int highestDegree = degree;
    for ( int i = degree; i <= 0; i--) {
         if ( coefficients[i] == 0 ) {
              highestDegree = i -1;
         } else {
              // if the value is non-zero
              break;
         }
    }
    float[] newCoefficients = new float[highestDegree + 1];
    for ( int i=0; i<= highestDegree; i++ ) {
           newCoefficients[i] = coefficients[i];
    }
    coefficients =   newCoefficients;
}

 public Poly differentiate(){
    int n = getDegree();
    Poly newResult = new Poly(n);
    if (n>0){   //checking if it has a degree
        for (int i = 1; i<= n; i++){
             newResult.coefficients[i-1]= coefficients[i] * (i); // shift degree by 1 and multiplies
     }
     return newResult;

     } else {
    return new Poly(); //empty
     }
    }


public Poly multiByConstantWithDegree(double c, int degree){ //used specifically for multiply poly
    int oldPolyDegree = this.getDegree();
    int newPolyDegree = oldPolyDegree + degree;
    Poly newResult = new Poly(newPolyDegree);
    //set all coeff to zero
    for (int i = 0; i<= newPolyDegree; i++){
        newResult.coefficients[i] = 0;
    }
    //shift by n degree
    for (int j = 0; j <= oldPolyDegree; j++){
        newResult.coefficients[j+degree] = coefficients[j] * (float)c;
    }

    return newResult;
 }
}
```

Out of this, I need to create a method that factors a Quadratic in two factors (if it has real roots), or in a constant ”1” polynomial factor and itself, if there are no real roots. The method should return an array of two QuadPoly objects, containing each factor.

```
public class QuadPoly extends Poly
{
    private float [] quadcoefficients;
     public QuadPoly() {
     super(2);

}

 public QuadPoly(float [] a) {
    quadcoefficients = new float[a.length];
    for (int i = 0; i <a.length; i ++){
        quadcoefficients[i] = a[i];

    if (quadcoefficients.length > 2){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Must be Quadratic");
    }

}
}
    public QuadPoly(Poly p){
        if (quadcoefficients.length > 2){
         throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Must be Quadratic");
    }
}

 public QuadPoly addQuad (QuadPoly p){
    return new QuadPoly(super.add(p));
}

public Poly multiplyQuadPoly (Poly p){
    if (quadcoefficients.length > 2){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Must be Quadratic");
    }
    Poly newResult = null;
    new Result = multiplyPoly(p);


}
}
}
```

Edit:

Sorry. This is what I have going on for the factoring so far. The big problem with it is that I'm not too sure how to get the inheritance to work properly.

This is my New Factoring. It doesn't work. Can anyone give me some hints to get on the right path? I understand that I need to return Poly so i'm replacing the arrays there as you can tell by the first if statement but it won't let me progress as its says it requires (int, float). I've casted it but it still won't allow me. Thanks

```
    public QuadPoly factor(){
    double a = (double) getCoefficient(0);
    double b = (double) getCoefficient(1);
    double c = (double) getCoefficient(2);
    QuadPoly newCoefficients = new QuadPoly(4);
    double equa = Math.sqrt((b*b) - (4*a*c));
    if (equa > 0){
        newCoefficients.setCoefficient(0, (float) (-b + equa)/(2*a));
        newCoefficients.setCoefficient(1, (float) (-b - equa)/(2*a));
    }
    if (equa ==0){
        newCoefficients[0] = 1;
        newCoefficients[1] = (-b + equa)/(2*a);
    }
    if (equa < 0){
        newCoefficients[0] = 0;
        newCoefficients[1] = 1;
    }
    return (QuadPoly) newCoefficients;
```

}

Comment: The factors of a quadratic polynomial are of degree 1. Use the [quadratic formula](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Quadratic_equation) to get the roots. That should get you started.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to explain how far you've gotten and what problem you have?

Comment: You should not need a `quadcoefficients` array in QuadPoly. All the functionality you need is in the base class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK you have made a reasonable attempt. Inheritance is simple here, all you need is the constructors:

```
class QuadPoly extends Poly{
  public QuadPoly(){ super(2); }
  public QuadPoly(float[] f){
    super(f);
    if(coefficients.length!=2) throw new IllegalArgumentException("not quad");
  }
}
```

and that's pretty much all! I hope you can see, that the same code as `Poly` is used for **everything else**, and the same field `coefficients` does all the same work as it did before.

Now, in the factorisation

1. you have dimmed your `double[] newCoefficients` as size 1. too small!
2. you have tried to square-root your discriminant without knowing that it is positive!
3. you are returning an array of 2 doubles as your answer. you need two `Poly`s. You haven't provided a method return type for `factor`

I suggest you use

```
 public QuadPoly[] factor(){
 }
```

as the signature. The rest is just maths!

Comment: the problem I have is that the coefficients in the original Class is private. We're not supposed to tamper with the code that was provided. Any way around it?

Comment: Yes, you don't need to use the `coefficients[]` array at all, if in your new code you use `getDegree()` (equivalent to coefficients.length) and `getCoefficient(i)` (equivalent to coefficients[i]).

Comment: I've changed it a bit again. Any help? I'm in your debt.

Comment: OK if you want to return 2 QuadPolys, you need `QuadPoly[] solutions = new QuadPoly[2];` at the start, and `return solutions;` at the end. The return type should be `QuadPoly[]`.  Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, this does. This was going to be the plan until it gave me an error when I tried to call a previous method from the class above called "setCoefficient (int , float). Since the formula I am using requires a double, I set everything to a double but that method, regardless of casting, won't take the double.

Comment: For the purposes of your exercise, ther won't be a great loss for using `float` over `double`! The "formula" doesn't **require** a double, right? Why don't you just cast the result of `Math.sqrt` to a `float`? Anyway, you are still trying to `sqrt` a negative number.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Helped a ton. I fixed the sqrt of the negative number by moving the sqrt process later on after it checks if the discriminant is positive, negative or equal to 0.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of subclassing `Poly` into `QuadPoly` is so that you can **reuse** as many of the old `Poly` methods as possible. Now, all your old methods use the array `float[] coefficients`, and your new `QuadPoly` **inherits** this field.

Why have you created a new field `quadcoefficients[]` ? It suffices to check in any constructor that there are only 3 members in the array, but to still harness the existing field `coefficients[]`.

If you do this, all your old methods will still work! Only, they will return generic `Poly`. Since the `QuadPoly` must conform to the contract of a `Poly`, this is probably OK. The method `multiplyCon` is the only one that could be guaranteed to return another `QuadPoly` anyway.

You don't seem to have attempted a factorisation yet. Do you have any ideas? Well, here's a clue: you'll need to use something like

```
if (DISCRIMINANT >= 0) {
} else{
}
```

Comment: I've edited my question and provided the method i'm working on for factoring. Could you help me a bit more with the inheritance? I'm no exactly sure how its supposed to work.